# Reading Unknown Value Types from XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have an XML file where the tag value can be an int, float, or string. How can I read this in using Linq?

Update #1:
I updated the XML to define the type for the element value. However, how would I translate it into the SettingData class.

XML:

```
<Settings>
    <data type="uint" x="Some_Value_Here">200</data>  <!-- Read this in as an int -->
    <data type="float" x="Some_Value_Here">200.0</data>  <!-- Read this in as a float -->
</Settings>
```

What I have so far:

```
settings = xDoc.Descendants("Settings").Select(ele => new SettingData()
              {
                  Data = (string)ele.Attribute("data"),
                  Value = (string)ele == "" ? 0 : ele, // not sure what to put here
              }).ToList();

class SettingData
{
    private string data;
    public string Data
    {
        get { return data; }
        set { data = value; }
    }

    private Object value;  // What would the type of this var be if I will use the "type" attribute to determine the type of this var.
    public Object Value
    {
        get { return this.value; }
        set { this.value = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: How would you tell the difference between a string that *happens* to be "200" and an integer value 200?

Comment: To add on Jon's comment, you need something to differentiate your value types. Else, your only way is a method that would arbitrarily read the values, maybe with regular expressions, as in "if it doesn't contain letters, it's a number, else it's a string; and if this number doesn't contain a decimal separator, it's an integer, else it's a float".

Comment: I have control over the xml file...maybe I can put another attribute in there for "type".

Comment: That's what is usually done, yes.

Comment: You could force it with a schema, but you're chasing your own tail.  Do "Settings" really need to be numeric values?  I suspect you're not doing any calculations with them, and a string would be fine.

Comment: Those values get published to the entire application. I think it would be more efficient to convert the values as soon as they get parsed vs parsing them everywhere they get used.

Comment: @user2970916 If by "more efficient" you mean "more convenient", very much yes. Efficiency isn't a big concern here, but calling `int.TryParse()` all over the place is a mess. Your idea of a type attribute looks very good to me. Either that or something like this: `<data x="A"><float>200</float></data><data x="A"><string>200</string></data>`.

Comment: @EdPlunkett How would I read it in correctly using Linq though? I have changed the value type of "Value" to be an Object.

Comment: @user2970916 Write a static method that takes `XNode` `<float/>`/`<int/>`/whatever, parses the node content appropriately, and returns the appropriate typed value as `Object`, then call that method in your LINQ.